# Add "permission" property to ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, permissions

I have a ASP.NET web application with 3 types of users: user, member, admin.

Now I'd like to create a method for every page with which I can check the user for his type and if he is not allowed to access this page, the user should be redirected to the home page.

Currently I have this kind of code in Page_Load of every page:

```
if (Session["userID"] != null)
        {
            User user = userDALC.Read(Convert.ToInt32(Session["userID"]));

            if (user.Type == 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
        }
```

This page is only visible to Members and Admins (2,3), if a user (1) wants to access this page, he will get redirected.

So, it's obvious that this code is absolutely not suitable for my use, because it repeats very often. (on every page)

Now, my idea was to add a property "permission" to each page, where I can set which user types are allowed to access the page.
And I also need a method which checks this permission property on every page.

Any ideas, how I can add such a property and any ideas where I can add this method? (maybe Masterpage?)

Comment: You can do it with a base page, but why don't you use asp.net authorization?

Answer (score 0):

There are several places you could implement such a method.  In the page load of the master page would work.

You could create your own Page class which inherits from the core Page class, implement the logic there, and use your custom Page class.

You could take the logic out of pages altogether and run it during the [Begin_Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx) handler in global.asax.  The thing to be aware of here is that this method runs for *all* requests handled by your application which may include requests for javascript, css, images, documents etc. Also you won't have access to the page object at this point so you'll need to identify the requests you want to check for authorization on based on the URL.

You could go even further and implement an [HttpHandler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001) that checks for authorization based on user identity and details of the request.  The logic would be similar to performing the check in global.asax.

As has already been pointed out however, asp.net does offer all this stuff pretty much out of the box via user roles.